# Message confirmation and partition in apache flink

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink

Coming from kafka. When a producer send a message to consumers, so producer will get a confirmation, if the message was successfully delivered or not.

How to figure out in flink, if the message has arrived to another stream or not?

What is exactly a partition in flink? Can I replay a partition like in kafka, when something went wrong?

Comment: If I get your questions right, you'd like to compare Flink and Kafka. These are quite different systems. Kafka is an event log to store and distribute streams (there's also Kafka Streams, but your questions seem to be about the event log part of Kafka). Flink is a stream processor and serves a similar purpose as Spark, Storm, or Samza but has some unique features. Since Kafka's event log and Flink serve very different purposes, their features cannot be compared. That being said, Flink has good support to read from and write to Kafka.

Comment: But Flink supports distribute streams also or not? I would like to use Flink for streaming purpose and as eventbus for microservices. Is it suiable? But  what is a DataSet in Flink?

Comment: Flink supports processing of bounded and unbounded streams. DataSet is Flink's abstraction for bounded streams (or batch processing). Flink is not an eventbus but it can be used as a *processing* framework for microservices, i.e., run the application logic. You can use Kafka or Kinesis or other log-based pub/sub services to store and distribute events.